# Intersection between a discrete set and a continuous set

Tags: sets

I have two sets:

$A=\{x| |x|<2\}, B=\{1,2,3\}$

and I know

```
A=Interval[{-2,2}]
B={1,2,3}
```

but

```
A \[Intersection] B
```

can not execute.

Comment: `Select[B, IntervalMemberQ[A, #] &]`

Comment: Never use upper-case letters for variables, sets, etc., as they may conflict with *Mathematica*'s system names.